# Call an External C++ function and Memory Leaks: is all allocated memory cleaned up after finishing Python script?

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

Python script calls an external C++ function (using ctypes). Memory leaks are possible when execution the C++ function.

Will all allocated memory (in C++ function) be automatically cleaned up after finishing of the Python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It will all be returned to the OS once the python interpreter exits. This is true for all processes - nothing specific to python or c++.